# List field names of layer in MXD file

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy

I have an ArcMap file (.MXD) that I want to search for its layers and then pick a layer and have Python show me the field names of the attribute table of that layer.

I have gotten so far that Python (ArcPy) lists me the layer names of the mxd but I cannot figure out how to get the field names.

In ArcMap itself I can easily do it this way:

```
fields = arcpy.ListFields(Layer)
for field in fields:
    print field.name
```

but how do I accomplish that outside of ArcMap through an MXD file? I have searched a lot and came up with nothing, so I am looking forward to your help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Access the mxd through the `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument` method. Then get the name and open the attributes table

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"path/Project.mxd")
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    print df.name
```

You can use `arcpy` and run a python script to show the table fileds by using the `ListFileds` method

```
import arcpy
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields("path/shapefile.shp")    
for field in fieldList:    
    print field.baseName
```

Comment: Yeah for a shapefile it's clear. The point is to do it with an MXD and point to the layer from there. Something like `arcpy.ListFields(mxd, Layer)`, but that doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @Khaled ok i added the option to iterate the shapefiles from the mxd

Comment: that other solution then gives me only the layers of the MXD. I want Python to open the MXD, present me a list of all layers from which I choose one (GUI) and then get the fields of that layer back. But I found a solution (see below). Had to trick some. Anyone has a better solution, is welcome to post it!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a good solution. I first get all the layers from the MXD file, then save each layers' name and source into a dictionary. Then I will choose the layer I want from a GUI and have that checked with the layer names in the dictionary through which I can then access the field names:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\MyMap.mxd") # loads my map
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd) # checks out the dataframes

layersources = {} # creates an empty dictionary

for d in df:
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", d) # lists all available layers

    for lyr in layers:
        layersources[lyr.name] = lyr.dataSource # fills keys and values of the layers (names and sources) into the dictionary

selecteditem = "the wanted layer"  # this I choose from a GUI then, just defined it here as a variable for testing purposes

fields = arcpy.ListFields(layersources[selecteditem]) # creates a list with all the fields from that layer

for field in fields: # iterates through the list of fields
    print field.name # and prints them one by one :-)
```

Comment: How exactly are you implementing this in a GUI? Do you use selecteditem var as a param or prompt that then is a drop down of the layers to choose from?